# What are the drawbacks with using UUID or GUID as a primary key?

Tags: postgresql, primary-key, datatypes, derby

I would like to build a distributed system. I need to store data in databases and it would be helpful to use an [UUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) or a [GUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier) as a primary key on some tables. I assume it's a drawbacks with this design since the UUID/GUID is quite large and they are almost random. The alternative is to use an auto-incremented INT or LONG.

What are the drawbacks with using UUID or GUID as a primary key for my tables?

I will probably use Derby/JavaDB (on the clients) and PostgreSQL (on the server) as DBMS.

Comment: Why would it be helpful? What drawbacks are you most focused on? The answer to every DB Question this vague is "it depends." Can you give us more details? Are you most interested in read or write performance? what level of distribution are we talking about?

Comment: @Brian: UUIDs in distributed systems is helpful since you can create the primary key on the clients and then upload the data asynchronously to the server. I'm mostly thinking about read performance drawbacks. Using many JOINs on UUIDs isn't maybe that good? In example a client add an item (UUID, name, supplier, creator) to an inventory system, and then the local database is synchronized with the central database on the server.

Comment: I think that without some more clarifying comments on this that it's going to at most be "it depends". Without those, I'm going to go for VtC.

Comment: There is an article that talks about GUID vs. non-GUID affect on clustered indexes in SQL Server that you might find interesting even though it's related to a different SQL product: x.co/Twpp

Comment: I noticed that [Derby doc](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.11/ref/crefsqlj31068.html) does not list UUID as a data type. You might want to consider an alternative such as the H2 Database Engine (a pure Java database like Derby) which does [list a UUID data type](http://h2database.com/html/datatypes.html#uuid_type). Of course Postgres does have excellent support for efficiently [storing](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-uuid.html), indexing, and [generating](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/uuid-ossp.html) UUID values.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**It depends on your generation function and size of the final tables**

GUIDs are intended to be *globally unique* identifiers. As discussed in the [Postgres 8.3 documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/datatype-uuid.html) there are no methodologies that are universally appropriate to generate these identifiers, but postgreSQL does ship with a few more useful candidates.

From the scope of your problem, and the need for *offline* writes, you've quite neatly boxed out the use of anything but a GUID, and therefore there are no compensatory advantages of other schemes.

From a functional standpoint, the key length is usually not an issue on any kind of modern system, depending on the number of reads and size of the table. As an alternative methodology, offline clients could batch new records *without* a primary key and simply insert them when reconnecting. As postgreSQL offers the "Serial" datatype, clients will never need to determine the ID if they can perform a simple write to the database.

Comment: Damn you sleep, you've gone and let Brian answer the question. Yes, the requirement for "offline updates" completely changed the whole concept there.

Comment: Muahahahaah! ::twirls mustache evilly::

Comment: Even with offline-writes it would be possible to use INTs. E.g. using two columns `{Node_ID, Item_ID}` where each node has a `Node_ID`, and an `Item_ID` that is auto-incremented per node.

Comment: @Jonas ~ Yes, that is feasible. However, one of the _reasons_ most people even contemplate GUIDs is for globally-separated replication of content to other databases. I mean the term itself is rather QED there.

Comment: With regards to master/slave architectures or sparse-connection clients + main server architectures, could it be feasible to use a global_id (SERIAL) on the master and a  global_id (BIGINT) + local_id (SERIAL) on the slaves. Slaves do their local work using local_id and commit when they can towards the master, the master receives the data and grants it a global_id which it returns to the slave, the slave updates global_id field (for reference use in talking to the server or to other slaves).

Comment: @MihaiStancu Why go to that trouble? UUIDs were invented for *just this purpose*: Sharing data amongst distributed systems without centralized coordination. UUIDs can be generated at any time unilaterally by any constituent. With UUIDs, instead of master-slave, the constituents act more like peers able to pass data back and forth independently.

Answer (score 22):

One more advice - never use GUIDs as part of clustered index.
GUIDs are not sequential, thus if they are part of clustered index, every time you insert new record, database would need to rearrange all its memory pages to find the right place for insertion, in case with int(bigint) auto-increment, it would be just last page.

Now if we look to some db realizations:
1.) MySQL - primary keys are clustered, with no option to change behavior - the recomendation is not to use GUIDs at all here
2.) Postgres, MS-SQL - you can make GUID as primary key unclustered, and use another field as clustered index, for example autoincrement int.

Comment: What you propose for Postgres can be done in MySQL as well, with slightly different stucture - auto_increment PK (clustered key), GUID with unique index (unclustered).

Comment: This isn't always true. Depending on the disk system throughput, synchronizing access to that last page might be your bottleneck. http://blog.kejser.org/2011/10/05/boosting-insert-speed-by-generating-scalable-keys/

Comment: "Unlike Microsoft SQL Server, clustering on an index in PostgreSQL does not maintain that order. You have to reapply the CLUSTER process to maintain the order." [How does CLUSTER ON improve index performance](http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/10-How-does-CLUSTER-ON-improve-index-performance.html)

Comment: A more condensed version of the information @bartolo-otrit linked to: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4796685/1394393. This answer really doesn't seem relevant to me, as this question is about PG and it seems to assume similarities to SQL Server and MySQL that don't exist.

Comment: ``database would need to rearrange all its memory pages to find the right place for insertion`` => I don't think that is the case with Postgres, as clustering is optional and new rows are stored unordered.

Answer (score 2):

It depends.

Seriously, with all you've given so far, this is about as far as you can go.

Why would it be helpful to use UUIDs? Why won't you use INTs? Why can't you just index on UUIDs later? Do you understand what it means to have a sorted list with the key of a UUID and insert a random (non-sequential) UUID after a few million rows?

What platform will this run on? How many disks? How many users? How many records?

Comment: As I wrote in my comment, if I use UUID the clients can add rows to the database without a connection to the server, and later synchronize with the server. I can not do that if I use INTs for primary key, because multiple clients may use the same primary key for different items then. Well, it's useless to sort the list on a UUID column, it would be more useful to sort it on a timestamp column. No, I don't know what it means to insert a random non-sequential UUID after a few million rows, that's why I ask this question.

Comment: The application will be written in Java and the clients my use Windows, Mac or Linux. The clients will use common desktop computers that usually have one disk. The number of users and records depends of how many customers I get, but it will be about 5000 per client and customer.

Comment: The offline comment changed everything. See what more details does?